# Loading Data from Category slider and combining with Category Select Page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui

So, I Have created a homePage where Category Slider are showing different Category. when ever I select a category it opening a subcategory page with `categoryId` which matches to the SubCategoryPage category list on the top of the screen and selected the same category the I select previously.selected category show the subcategory List. so in a sense. each category represent different subcategory list. now i want to change the category section on second page. if I press any of the category on the top category list it will render and fetch the subcategory list on the page.

here is my `categorySlider.dart` file code

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';
import 'package:shimmer/shimmer.dart';
import '../models/Category.dart';

import '../apis/CategoryApiServiceProvider.dart';
import 'category_page.dart';

class CategorySliderV2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const CategorySliderV2({super.key});

  @override
  State<CategorySliderV2> createState() => _CategorySliderV2State();
}

class _CategorySliderV2State extends State<CategorySliderV2> {
  CategoryApiServiceProvider _categoryApiServiceProvider = new CategoryApiServiceProvider();
  List<String> imageList = <String>[];
  
  var baseImageUrl = "http://admin.weservebd.com/../storage/";
  var baseUrl = "http://admin.weservebd.com/api/";

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Category?>(
      future: _categoryApiServiceProvider.getCategory(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          List<Data>? list = snapshot.data?.data;
          for (var category in list!) {
            precacheImage(
              CachedNetworkImageProvider('$baseImageUrl${category.image?.substring(7)}'),
              context,
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              right: 8,
            ),
            itemCount: list.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return  Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 130,

                      // width: double.infinity,
                      child: Material(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        elevation: 4,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  side: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF1818B4)))),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) {
                                return CategoryPage(
                                  categoryId :  list[index].id,
                                );
                              }
                              )
                            );
                          },
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              ClipRRect(
                                
                                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                  imageUrl: '$baseImageUrl''${list[index].image?.substring(7)}',
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                  height: 120,
                                  width: 120,
                                )
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
            },
          );
        }
        else{
          return _buildShimmerSlider();
        }
      },
    );
  }
  Widget _buildShimmerSlider() {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        right: 8,
      ),
      itemCount: 5, // Number of shimmer placeholders
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Shimmer.fromColors(
          baseColor: Colors.grey[300]!,
          highlightColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 130,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

this is my CategorySlider and List of SubCategory page which is in `CategoryPage.dart` file

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:shimmer/shimmer.dart';
import 'package:we_serve/models/SubCategory.dart' as sub;
import 'package:we_serve/pages/custom_appbar.dart';
import 'package:we_serve/pages/subcategory_page.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

import '../apis/CategoryApiServiceProvider.dart';
import '../apis/SubCategoryApiServiceProvider.dart';
import '../models/Category.dart';
import '../utils/route.dart';

class CategoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  int? categoryId;
  CategoryPage({super.key, this.categoryId});

  @override
  State<CategoryPage> createState() => _CategoryPageState();
}

class _CategoryPageState extends State<CategoryPage> {

  CategoryApiServiceProvider _categoryapiServiceProvider = new CategoryApiServiceProvider();
  SubCategoryApiServiceProvider _subcategoryapiServiceProvider = new SubCategoryApiServiceProvider();
  
  var baseImageUrl = "https://admin.weservebd.com/../storage/";
  var baseUrl = "https://admin.weservebd.com/api/";

  bool orderListCount = true;
  int orderCount = 0;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState;

    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    var currentUser = _auth.currentUser;

    if (currentUser != null) {
      String email = currentUser.email.toString();
      // print(email);
      getOrderListCount(email);
    }
  }


  

  void getOrderListCount(String email) async {
    try {
      var response = await Dio().get('$baseUrl' 'get_cart_item_count/' '$email');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        setState(() {
          orderCount = response.data['count'] as int;
          orderListCount = false;
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // print(e);
      orderListCount = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int selectedItemIndex = widget.categoryId! - 1;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(title: "All Category", orderCount: orderCount,),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Color(0xFF1818B4),
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 125,
            // color: Color(0xFF1818B4),
            child: FutureBuilder<Category?> (
              future: _categoryapiServiceProvider.getCategory(),
              builder: (context, snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasData){
                  List<Data>? list = snapshot.data?.data;
                  for (var category in list!) {
                    precacheImage(
                      CachedNetworkImageProvider('$baseImageUrl${category.image?.substring(7)}'),
                      context,
                    );
                  }
                  return ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: 8,
                    ),
                    itemCount: list.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      bool isSelected = selectedItemIndex == index;

                      return Container(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () => {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedItemIndex = index;
                            })
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            color: isSelected
                                ? Color.fromARGB(255, 100, 100, 230)
                                : Color(0xFF1818B4),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                ClipRRect(
                                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                    imageUrl: '$baseImageUrl${list[index].imageCategory?.substring(7)}',
                                    // color: Colors.transparent,
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                    height: 125,
                                    width: 125,
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }
                else{
                  return _buildShimmerCategorySlider();
                  // return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            )
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder<sub.SubCategory?>(
              future: _subcategoryapiServiceProvider.getSubCategory(widget.categoryId),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                // print(snapshot.data);
                if(snapshot.hasData){
                  List<sub.Data>? sublist = snapshot.data?.data;
                  for (var category in sublist!) {
                    precacheImage(
                      CachedNetworkImageProvider('$baseImageUrl${category.image?.substring(7)}'),
                      context,
                    );
                  }
                  // print(sublist);
                  return ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    itemCount: sublist.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        height: 100,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) {
                                    return SubCategoryPage(
                                      subcategoryId : sublist[index].id,
                                      subcategoryName : sublist[index].subcategoryName,
                                  );
                                }
                              )
                            );
                          },
                          child: Card(
                            // color: Colors.blue,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                side: BorderSide(
                                  color: Color(0xFF1818B4),
                                )),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  ClipRRect(
                                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                      imageUrl:'$baseImageUrl${sublist[index].image?.substring(7)}',
                                      // color: Colors.transparent,
                                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                      height: 150,
                                      width: 100,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 20,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    '${sublist[index].subcategoryName}',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      // fontSize: 24,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    );
                }
                else{
                  return _buildShimmerSubCategorySlider();
                }
              },
            ) 
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget _buildShimmerCategorySlider() {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        right: 8,
      ),
      itemCount: 5, // Number of shimmer placeholders
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Shimmer.fromColors(
          baseColor: Colors.blueGrey[300]!,
          highlightColor: Colors.blueGrey[100]!,
          child: Container(
            width: 125,
            height: 125,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }


  Widget _buildShimmerSubCategorySlider() {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        right: 8,
      ),
      itemCount: 5, // Number of shimmer placeholders
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Shimmer.fromColors(
          baseColor: Colors.grey[300]!,
          highlightColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
  
}
```

If any file like Model or controller need to modify just ask me. I am stuck on this. Can anyone please solve this issue?